# Python - split matrix data into separate columns

Tags: python, matrix

I have read data from a file and stored into a matrix (frag_coords):

```
frag_coords =
[[  916.0907976    -91.01391344   120.83596334]
 [  916.01117655   -88.73389753   146.912555  ]
 [  924.22832597   -90.51682575   120.81734705]

...
 [  972.55384732   708.71316138    52.24644577]
 [  972.49089559   710.51583744    72.86369124]]

type(frag_coords) = 
class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'
```

I do not have any issues when reordering the matrix by a specified column. For example, the code below works just fine:

```
order = np.argsort(frag_coords[:,2], axis=0)
```

My issue is that:

```
len(frag_coords[0]) = 1
```

I need to access the individual numbers of the first row individually, I've tried splitting it, transforming it into a list and everything seems to return the 3 numbers not as columns but rather as a single element with len=1. I need help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a `matrix` instead of an `ndarray`. Are you sure you want that?

For a matrix, indexing the first row alone leads to *another* matrix, a row matrix. Check `frag_coords[0].shape`: it will be `(1,3)`. For an `ndarray`, it would be `(3,)`.

If you only need to index the first row, use two indices:

```
frag_coords[0,j]
```

Or if you store the row temporarily, just index into it as a row matrix:

```
tmpvar = frag_coords[0]  # shape (1,3) 
print(tmpvar[0,2])       # for column 2 of row 0
```

If you don't need too many matrix operations, I'd advise that you use `np.array`s instead. You can always read your data into an array directly, but at a given point you can just transform an existing matrix with `np.array(frag_coords)` too if you wish.

Comment: Thank you!! I thought I needed to have a matrix to perform my calculations (nothing fancy, mainly coordinate transformations and rotations) but I can and definitely will use the array instead!

Comment: @IsisDorus I'm glad I could help:) For python version 3.5 and later, with sufficiently new numpy version, one can use the `@` operator for matrix multiplication, which works for arrays too. Otherwise one needs to use `numpy.dot` to do the same. Anyway, arrays are usually much more convenient:)